# Postgres function which accepts array and then to evaluate it

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I want to accept postgress function which takes an argument to determine what all features should user have access to.

In Javascript/Typescript I would ideally do something like this

```
const a = ['featureA', 'featureB', 'featureC']; 

function unlockFeatures (abc) {
 let unlock = ''
 if (abc.includes('featureA')) {
  unlock = 'somethingA'
 }
 else if (abc.includes('featureB')) {
  unlock = 'somethingB'
 }
 else if (abc.includes('featureC')) {
  unlock = 'somethingC'
 }
 return unock
}

unlockFeatures(a)
```

How can I write equivalent of this in postgres/sql function where I can pass array to function?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, I guess

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION unlockFeatures(abc TEXT[])
  RETURNS TEXT  
  LANGUAGE plpgsql  AS $$
DECLARE
    unlock TEXT:= '';
BEGIN   
    IF (SELECT 'featureA' = ANY($1)) THEN 
        unlock:= 'somethingA';
    ELSIF (SELECT 'featureB' = ANY($1)) THEN
        unlock:= 'somethingB';
    ELSEIF (SELECT 'featureC' = ANY($1)) THEN
        unlock:= 'somethingC';
    END IF;
    RETURN unlock;
END; $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the Javascript includes() method PostgreSQL has the [ANY()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) function.

The [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression checks multiple condition.

At the end SQL function return [last query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-sql.html):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(abc text[])
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
SELECT case 
when 'featureA' = any(abc) then 'somethingA'
when 'featureB' = any(abc) then 'somethingB'
when 'featureC' = any(abc) then 'somethingC'
end$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

SELECT test(
    ARRAY['featureA', 'featureB', 'featureC', 'featureD']
);
```